# John Horváth - Topological Vector Spaces and Distributions Volume 2

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, reference-request, distribution-theory, topological-vector-spaces

In at least three places in the book Topological Vector Spaces and Distributions, written by John Horváth, the author comments on a second volume of his book that has never been published.

In particular, we have the following sentence: *Finally, we state the following fundamental result, whose proof is postponed to Volume 2 (Chapter 6, $\S$11).*  Which implies that this book would have at least 6 chapters.

I would like to know if there is an unpublished version of this book, or a handwritten version, which may have been used in one of your courses.

Comment: I tried to look for it in hungarian, but I couldn't find anything.

Comment: I thought about contacting his PhD student, Matthias Jakob Stark, to see if he had any information, but I couldn't find his email.

Comment: There is a school of functional analysis in Austria who specialize in topological vector spaces and know the work of Horvath very well. So you could try to contact, e.g., Norbert Ortner https://techmath.uibk.ac.at/mathematik/ortner/ or his students like Christian Bargetz, https://www.uibk.ac.at/mathematik/functionalanalysis/staff.html

Comment: The first volume has only 4 chapters so I rather think the second volume, should it ever appear/have appeared would have started at chapter 5.  That was fairly common practice back in the 1960s when the first volume was published.